# Joining same table multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables Person an Department - where each person has multiple departments registered against him.

```
Person

id|name|dept1|dept2|dept3
1 |Jane|100  |102  |106

Dept
id |Name
100|Accounts
...
102|HR
...
106|Admin
```

Whats the most elegant sql to display Jane's record as follows:

```
    Jane|Accounts|HR|Admin
```

Comment: Why not give it a try?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP does not seem to have done any effort to find the solution.

Comment: @PatrickHofman A quick search would have give him some solution. Anyway using Pivot and UnPivot might help him  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this. And work on your naming convention to make all column names unique independent of table.

```
SELECT
Person.id, Person.name, dept1.Name, dept2.Name, dept3.Name
LEFT JOIN Dept dept1 ON dept1.id = Person.dept1
LEFT JOIN Dept dept2 ON dept2.id = Person.dept2
LEFT JOIN Dept dept3 ON dept3.id = Person.dept3
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will let you join the same table multiple times. You just give each join a different alias

```
SELECT * 
FROM Person AS P 
     INNER JOIN Dept AS D1 ON P.dept1 = D1.id 
     INNER JOIN Dept AS D2 ON P.dept2 = D2.id
WHERE P.name = 'Jane'
```

Ideally you would normalise the data in your Person table and have a linking table between Person and Dept e.g. `PersonDepartmentLinking` (or whatever convention you have for linking table naming conventions), assuming you have any control over the schema and it's possible to add the relationship that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [STUFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)  in this case

```
   Select name,
   Stuff((Select distinct ', ' + cast(Name as varchar(20))
           From #Dept t2
           Where t2.Id = t1.Id
           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') 
    From Person t1
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know is a join for each column.
But if you are in the way of designing the tables, i suggest you to normalize the DB.
If a person need an extra dept column, you need to alter the table to add a new property of person.

For me, 3 entities are needed:
- Person
- Department
- person_department_assignation